# DSPack and video antialiasing

Tags: video, smoothing, dspack

i using DSPack to play video files. Unfortunately lt has no any smooting when TVideoWindow resizing. Is there a way in DSPack to apply some resampling filter (like Lanczoc, Hann, etc) to smooth the playing video?